# Как сделать обтекание списком?

Tags: flexbox, float

Есть такой код(образно):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.clearfix::after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: "";
}

.clearfix::before {
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
.title {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
.text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="title">
    fet fet fet fet
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>12</li>
  </ol>
    <div class="text">
    fet fet fet
  </div>
</div>
```

Требуется что бы элементы списка обтекали красный блок(слева и снизу) и желтый блок(справа и сверху).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно добиться желаемого эффекта???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для элемента, который должен находиться слева, задаёте класс ".left", а для того, что справа - ".right".

Результат:
https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/bGbrpRa

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0000FF;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  background: #ff0000;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 4 * 3);
  background: #67268b;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item">1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item right">right</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item">4</li>
  <li class="item">5</li>
  <li class="item">6</li>
  <li class="item">7</li>
  <li class="item">8</li>
  <li class="item">9</li>
  <li class="item">10</li>
  <li class="item">11</li>
  <li class="item left">left</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это не то, что нужно:) Элементы списка должны обтекать отдельные блоки. В моем коде сверху нужный эффект достигнут с красным блоком, а вот с желтым не получилось

Comment: @МаксимЧервяков, а зачем усложнять? Ведь каждый элемент списка - это и есть отдельный блок.

Comment: по макету так не получится, там разные смысловые блоки и список

Comment: Поделитесь макетом (можно просто скриншот) . Интересно посмотреть

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/df078342168338950838bb17da92547b

Comment: В общем, Вы сами себе усложняете жизнь. Есть обычная сетка. Вот вариант на Float: http://bit.ly/30N3B8P, вот вариант на Flexbox: http://bit.ly/30Mh40J. Не морочьте себе голову "смыслами". Дизайнер может так "завернуть" макет, что соблюдая "смыслы" никогда не получится ничего сверстать.

Comment: Спасибо! Опыта мало, хотелось все сделать максимально "по-семантике" :) Буду делать с флексами, еще раз благодарю!:)